# Как правильно записать span элемент в переменную для дальнейшей работы с ним?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Объясню свой вопрос на примере, я работаю на скриптом, и мне в консоли не правильно записывается спан.

вот кусок кода[image: скрипт]

я беру определенный элемент в строке и в столбце и записываю в переменную, после таких операций вывожу все в консоль лог для проверки как все записалось и вижу то, что на скриншоте, а то бишь Object NodeList, я ожидал другой результат, именно я ожидал 2 варианта записи в переменную - либо span.GoodNumber, либо span.BadNumber.

Но не знаю почему записывается именно Object NodeList. Если кто сможет объяснить как правильно записать это все, буду благодарен.

UPD:

Я ожидаю получить из этого селектора value = span.BadNumber или span.GoodNumber для блока кода где я буду приравнивать значения
Этой мой код:

```
let value1 = document.querySelectorAll('table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(5) > span');
let value2 = document.querySelectorAll('table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > span');
let value3 = document.querySelectorAll('table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(5) > span');
```

Потом:

```
if (value1 && value2 && value3 === BadNumber)
```

BadNumber переменная в которую записывается `(document.querySelectorAll('table.BetsTable > tbody > tr.MyBet > td > span.BadNumber'))`

Я загрузил еще сайт, логика такая, нужно чтобы с первых трех строк профита производилась проверка на BadNumber, если все 3 строки равны BadNumber, то запускается скрипт.

[image: сайт]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92850/discussion-on-question-by-daymanking----span---).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let value1 = document.querySelector(
  'table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(5) > span');
...

if (value1.classList.contains("BadNumber") && 
    value2.classList.contains("BadNumber") && 
    value3.classList.contains("BadNumber")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я попробую, все кто помогал, я отблагодарю полным скриптом на майн крипту)

Comment: Помогали Stranger in the Q, Grundy, Igor - как будет допилен скрипт, я вышлю в лички вам свой скрипт)

Comment: напиши пожалуйста, куда можно тебе написать в личку)

Answer (score 1):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает **коллекцию** элементов, ты же хотел получить конкретные элементы, для этого нужно было либо взять их по индексу, например `[0]`, либо использовать [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), который как раз и возвращает нужный элемент.

Однако можно обойтись одним вызовом [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Можно выбрать сразу нужные элементы с нужным классом, и проверить их количество:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll(
    'table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(5) > span.Bad, ' +
    'table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > span.Bad, ' + 
    'table.BetsTable > tbody >  tr.MyBet:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(5) > span.Bad').length == 3) {
    // все три с классом Bad
}
```